# NSNumber? to a value of type String? in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2

So I can't figure this out, am I supposed to change the '.text' to something else or do I have to go about converting the string into a double?

Here is the code

```
if item != nil {
    // the errors I keep getting for each one is
    unitCost.text = item?.unitCost //cannot assign to a value 'NSNumber?' to a value of type 'String?'
    total.text = item?.total  //cannot assign to a value 'NSNumber?' to a value of type 'String?'
    date.text = item?.date //cannot assign to a value 'NSDate?' to a value of type 'String?'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign an invalid type to the `text` property. The text property is of type `String?` as stated by the compiler error. You are trying to assign an `NSNumber` or `NSDate`. The expected type is a `String` or `nil` and so you must ensure that you provide *only* those two possibilities. As a result, you need to convert your numbers and dates into strings.

In Swift, there is no need to use format specifiers. Instead, best practice is to use string interpolation for simple types like numbers:

```
unitCost.text = "\(item?.unitCost!)"
total.text    = "\(item?.total!)"
```

For dates, you can use `NSDateFormatter` to produce a human-friendly date in a desired format:

```
let formatter       = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle

date.text           = "\(formatter.stringFromDate(date))"
```

While we're at it, why not use optional binding instead of `nil` comparison:

```
if let item = item {
    // Set your properties here
}
```

Comment: Would it still work if I set up a datepicker keyboard for the date or would I have to change something there?

Comment: A date picker keyboard (assuming you're using a `UIDatePicker` in a text field's `inputView` or similar) will give you back an `NSDate`, which you will still have to format appropriately to display to the user. Regardless of how you arrive at your `NSDate` object, using an `NSDateFormatter` (preferably a cached instance)  is the best solution for displaying dates on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
unitCost.text = String(format: "%d", item?.unitCost?.integerValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extension for Double/NSNumber/NSDate

```
extension Double {
    func toString() -> String {
        return NSNumberFormatter().stringFromNumber(self) ?? ""
    }
}

extension NSNumber {
    func toString() -> String {
        return NSNumberFormatter().stringFromNumber(self) ?? ""
    }
}

var doubleValue: Double?
doubleValue?.toString()
```

if doubleValue is not set it returns empty string. You can make toString() return String? too.. depends on what you need

also, item != nil check is not required in your code as it is optional.

Answer (score 0):

@dbart "\(item?.unitCost)" displays an optional value as String, like Optional(5) rather than 5, we need to unwrap the value

Answer (score -1):

check this code:

```
if let requiredItem = item {
unitCost.text = requiredItem.unitCost ? "\(requiredItem.unitCost)" : ""
total.text = requiredItem.total ? "\(requiredItem.total)" : ""
date.text = requiredItem.date ? "\(requiredItem.date)" : ""
}
```